Is creating a JMSContext from ConnectionFactory for each HTTP request good for a high load environment?
New to JMS implementation. Doing this in Quarkus
When getting a http request from user, then to place that request inside the requestQueue , creating an instance of JMSContext from connectionFactory
If this approach okay for a production env for high load or there is some pooling mechanism to do or need to use only single JMSContext and use that for sending messages to different RequestQueue as per the API need

Did my answer address your question? If so, please accept it to help other users who have this same question in the future. Thanks!

If you use a pooled connection factory that shouldn't be a problem in terms of performance. That pattern has been used extensively in Java EE for years.

What are the option of PooledCOnnection factory for Quarkus with RabbitMQ. Will I need to implement custom pool factory or there is some existing

If you're using the RabbitMQ JMS client then you can use this pool. It's also available as a Quarkus extension. If you're not using JMS I'm not sure what your option(s) would be.
